# Update Manager will not Install Updates

Tags: update-manager, uninstall

When I go into Update Manager it says that I have 161 Updates, I hit the Install Button and a Box comes up that says "To install or remove Softwere you need to Authenticate" I put in My Password and then I hit Install again Another box comes up that says "Applying Changes" I sit back and wait and Nothing happens!  I even let it continue Overnight & when I checked it the next Morning there was still nothing Happening so I hit the Cancel Button. at th top of the page it reads "Important Software for this Computer"
     Why wont anything Install?

Comment: Update form the Terminal, press Alt+F2 or Control+T and type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` .

Comment: This is probably because of some problem with an update of a specific package.  Running the commands suggested by Uri above will allow you to see what is causing the problem, and if you can't resolve it, let us know more information so we can try to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Just <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```